# Raspberry Pi Camera Error: Unicam Has Timed Out

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera

I have been trying to get my raspberry pi camera to work for a while now. Probably every 2 weeks or so I would fire up the raspberry pi to convince myself that something changed but whatever I try, libcamera-hello or libcamera-still always produces the same error:

```
ERROR RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1812 Unicam has timed out!   
ERROR RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1813 Please check that your camera sensor connector is attached securedly.
ERROR RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1814 Alternatively, try another cable and/or sensor.
```

I have tested this on 2 Raspberry Pi 4 model Bs, 2 Cameras(the UC-873 and the UC291), 3 different cables, but only one SD card. I am using an official raspberry pi power supply. I have tried both Buster and the newest version of Bullseye hoping that it would be the software that is causing the problem. For some reason on my newest camera, the UC-783, instead of the Unicam error, it just says that there are no cameras detected and the code:

```
vcgencmd get_camera
```

results with

```
supported=1 detected=0
```

My config file looks like this:

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

# Automatically load overlays for detected cameras
camera_auto_detect=1

# Automatically load overlays for detected DSI displays
display_auto_detect=1

# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

# Disable compensation for displays with overscan
disable_overscan=1

[cm4]
# Enable host mode on the 2711 built-in XHCI USB controller.
# This line should be removed if the legacy DWC2 controller is required
# (e.g. for USB device mode) or if USB support is not required.
otg_mode=1

[all]

[pi4]
# Run as fast as firmware / board allows
arm_boost=1

[all]
gpu_mem=124
```

I feel like I have tried every possible solution. Could it be an option that I somehow damaged both cameras or all cables? I have made sure not to switch out a camera when the raspberry pi was on so the only way I think I could have done something is by static electricity.

Any suggestions?